# Datatable binding to a form is not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

i am having a form which are having 4 lables and these lables value are displayed in the 4 textboxs, i am using MVVM and binding these textboxs with the Datatble which is coming through the typed dataset not the problem here is when i add a new row in the datatable with default values of columns and update ui by calling onpropertychanged event from my viewmodel , these values are not getting reflected on the form.

Before adding a new row in the table , i am removing all previous rows and then add.

TIA.

Saurabh

Comment: Can you provide the XAML you're using to bind to the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're binding directly to the DataTable itself in whatever ItemsControl you're using, then rasing `PropertyChanged` on your ViewModel probably isn't getting recognized as changing the bound entity.  Fundamentally, DataTable and the child entities don't support `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so they are not acting the way the data binding would like them to be.

To "Hit it with a hammer" you could try Rasing `PropertyChanged` with String.Empty for the parameter, which means "re-bind everything", but that can be quite expensive, depending on the page.

Some better options:

You could try implementing INotifyCollectionChanged in the typed DataTable types, but this might be quite a pain depending on how complex your schema is.

A "more recommended" approach would be to look at going to something like Entity Framework to do your ORM work.  You could then get back real entities that could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly.

Another acceptable approach would be to use something like AutoMapper to convert the data table rows into real ViewModel entities and `ObservableCollection<>`s.  You, of course, need to map them back to your data storage entities (be those data rows or whatever) at the end of the day, but there are plenty of tools to make this easier.

Generally speaking, not many people would recommend using DataTables (strongly typed or otherwise) for moving data around inside your application anymore.  Too many of the useful tools (e.g. Validation, ORM, Data Binding) require you to have a real object that you can implement your own interfaces on (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`).  If you are working on a relatively "Green Field" application, I would spend a little time with Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL (which appears to be deprecated in favor of EF) and see if you can use one of these (or another ORM like NHibernate) to fill your needs.